# How to Use OpenRiaServices with Entity Framework 6.4.4

Tags: entity-framework-6, wcf-ria-services

I am trying to use Entity Framework 6.4.4 inside a .net6 project. I was able to create the .edmx file and was able to generate the entities. All is working well. Now I want to use Open Ria Services to create LinqToEntitiesDomainService. But the problem is, the LinqToEntitiesDomainService expects ObjectContext as TContext but I am working with EF 6 and I have DB context.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Their nuget package description claims that it works with EF6.4.4 but so far I can't make it work with EF6.4.4 due to DBContext vs ObjectContext issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation into the code, I realized that I don't have to use `LinqToEntitiesDomainService` but instead `DbDomainService` since the former works with `ObjectContext` (EF < 4) and the later works with `DbContext` (EF > 4).

Either this critical information was missing from the Help docs I went through or I missed it. Nonetheless, my issue is resolved now.